# Curvature function and rate of change of angle

Tags: differential-geometry

> Let $\gamma:(a,b)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ be a smooth curve with $\| \dot{\gamma}(s)\|=1$ for all $s\in (a,b)$. Fix $s_0\in (a,b)$ and let the unit vector $\dot{\gamma}(s_0)$ be represented by $(\cos \phi_0,\sin\phi_0)$.  Then there is smooth function $\phi$ with $\phi(s_0)=\phi_0$  such that 
>   $$\dot{\gamma}(s)=(\cos\phi(s),\sin\phi(s))$$
>   for all $s\in (a,b)$.

The proof goes as follows: let 
$$\dot{\gamma}(s)=(f(s),g(s))$$
so that $f(s)^2+g(s)^2=1$ for all $s$. Define 
$$\phi(s)=\phi_0 + \int_{s_0}^s (f\dot{g}-g\dot{f})du$$
It is then shown that this is required $\phi$ in the theorem.

**Q.** I didn't get intuition for choice (definition) of $\phi$. How do we justify the choice of $\phi$ above?

**Reference:** Elementary differential geometry by Pressley, Proposition 2.2.1 (New edition)

---

Using the explicitly defined angular function $\phi$, the curvature function is given by 
$$\kappa_s =\frac{d\phi}{ds}.$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that

$$\gamma'(s)=(f(s),g(s))$$ and $$\gamma'(s)=(\cos\phi(s),\sin\phi(s))$$ gives

$$\phi(s)=\arctan \dfrac{g(s)}{f(s)}$$ (if $f(s)\ne 0.$)

Taking derivatives we get

$$\phi'(s)=\dfrac{1}{1+\dfrac{g(s)^2}{f(s)^2}}\dfrac{f(s)g'(s)-g(s)f'(s)}{f(s)^2}=f(s)g'(s)-g(s)f'(s).$$

Comment: If $f(s)=0$ one can proceed in a similar way having in mind that $cotan \phi=\frac{f}{g}.$ Note that since $f^2+g^2=1$ it is not possible to have $f(s)=g(s)=0.$

Comment: At some point $f(s_1)$ can be $0$ and at some point $g(s_2)$ can be $0$; how can we proceed then?

Comment: If $f(s)\ne 0$ use $\tan$ and if $g(s)\ne 0$ use $\mathrm{cotan}.$ In any case you'll get $\phi'(s)=f(s)g'(s)-g(s)f'(s).$

Answer (score 0):

Intuition is that you want to get $\phi$ by integration of $\kappa=\frac{d\phi}{ds}$.
You get $$\phi(s)=\phi_0 + \int_{s_0}^s \kappa(u) du$$
by fundamental theorem of calculus. From serret formulae you can derive $$\kappa=\langle \ddot  \gamma,J \dot \gamma \rangle$$ 
where $\dot\gamma$ interpreted as tangential vector field $T$ and $J$ a rotation anticlockwise by $1/2 \pi$.
This will yield you 
$$\phi(s)=\phi_0 + \int_{s_0}^s \langle \dot T(u),JT(u) \rangle du=\phi_0 + \int_{s_0}^s (f\dot{g}-g\dot{f}) du$$ as desired.